# Different output when using count and group by

Tags: sql, vertica

When trying to get a count of IDs I get a different answer when grouping by day vs when I am not.

```
select cv.CONV_DAY, count(distinct cv.CLICK_ID)
from
    clickcache.click cc
right join(
        select distinct cv.CLICK_ID, cv.CONV_DAY, cv.PIXEL_ID
        from clickcache.CONVERSION cv
        where cv.CLICK_ID IS NOT NULL) cv ON cv.CLICK_ID = cc.ID
where   cc.ADV_ACCOUNT_ID = 25176
    and cv.CONV_DAY between '2016-8-01' AND '2016-08-07' 
    and AMP_CLICK_STATUS_ID = 1
    AND pixel_id IN 
                   (SELECT DISTINCT conversion_pixel_id
                FROM
                    ampx.campaign_event_funnel ef
                JOIN ampx.campaign cp ON
                    cp.id = ef.campaign_id
                    AND cp.campaign_status_id = 1
                WHERE
                    ef.account_id IN(25176)  
                    AND include_optimization = 1 )
group by 1
order by 1 asc
```

---

This yields 170 which is the correct answer and the I want. This, on the other hand, displays 157.

```
select count(distinct cv.CLICK_ID)
from
    clickcache.click cc
right join(
        select distinct cv.CLICK_ID, cv.CONV_DAY, cv.PIXEL_ID
        from clickcache.CONVERSION cv
        where cv.CLICK_ID IS NOT NULL) cv ON cv.CLICK_ID = cc.ID
where   cc.ADV_ACCOUNT_ID = 25176
    and cv.CONV_DAY between '2016-8-01' AND '2016-08-07' 
    and AMP_CLICK_STATUS_ID = 1
    AND pixel_id IN 
                   (SELECT DISTINCT conversion_pixel_id
                FROM
                    ampx.campaign_event_funnel ef
                JOIN ampx.campaign cp ON
                    cp.id = ef.campaign_id
                    AND cp.campaign_status_id = 1
                WHERE
                    ef.account_id IN(25176)  
                    AND include_optimization = 1 )
```

---

My question is why do I get this discrepancy and how to fix it to get a proper count?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're grouping by day, the `count` shouldn't be higher than the overall `count`, but rather a subset based on the day.  Perhaps you have 170 days and think that's the count?  Sample data and expected results would be helpful...

Comment: I guess the same `cv.CLICK_ID` 's got into different days so sum of CLICK_ID per days greater than count distinct CLICK_ID's in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Your count dependents from right query, maybe you have duplicate row?

example

```
table1
id name value
1 2 3
```

table2

```
id name value
1 4 5
2 6 3
1 6 3
```

right join tables on value get result

```
select * from table1 a right join table2 b on a.value = b.value 

1 2 3 2 6 3 
1 2 3 1 6 3 

    select count(distinct a.value) 
from (select a.id, a.name, a.value, b.id, b.name, b.value 
from table1 a right join table2 b on a.value = b.value)

result is 1 

    select b.id, count(distinct a.value) 
from (select a.id, a.name, a.value, b.id, b.name, b.value 
from table1 a right join table2 b on a.value = b.value group)
    group by b.id

result is two rows
2 1
1 1
```

My guess is that, you have a problem for this reason.